# C++ system() on bash script with at executes differently

Tags: shell-script, c++, at

C++ script, compiled with `g++ -std=c++11`

```
   #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        system("./temp.bash");
    }
```

Bash script

```
    TIME="now +1 minutes"
    STRING="Output File Test 7 SUCCESS!!!"
    echo -e "echo \"$STRING\" >> output.txt
    <EOT>" | at $TIME
```

with `<EOT>` meaning the character \x04

in C++ the last line looks like `"echo -e \"echo \\\"$STRING\\\" >> output.txt\n\x04\" | at $TIME"`

The difference between the two methods of calling `./temp.bash` (by calling compiled C++ script vs calling directly from command line) is that the `-e` flag is written into the `/atjobs` file at the beginning of the line when called via C++.

This seems like a bug. Why does this happen?

Comment: You didn't use a shebang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` ain't portable; the `bash` builtin `echo` differs from that of the system `/bin/echo` binary. Stripped of the complications of the `at` call and whatnot we observe

```
$ sh -c 'echo -e "echo hi"'
-e echo hi
$ bash -c 'echo -e "echo hi"'
echo hi
$ bash -c '/bin/echo -e "echo hi"'
-e echo hi
$
```

The `system` in C++ (or also C) calls `sh` which (likely) has no `echo` builtin and thus the system `/bin/echo` is used and the `-e` is printed as-is because that system `echo` has no idea what `-e` is. Same story when via `bash` the system `/bin/echo` is used. You might consider instead `printf` for better portability, or to avoid awkward `sh` calls and instead just fork/exec and write to `at` directly.

Comment: The at command always uses /bin/sh. It actually prints - `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh`.

Comment: `at` is irrelevant. `sh` via `system` runs your "bash" code as `sh`.